# How to scrape a particular field from a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape "Fees from" value from this website https://www.worldremit.com/en/mexico.

[image: Value to be extracted marked in green]

I came up close but unable to move forward. Can anyone help me out?

```
import argparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import csv

#parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#parser.add_argument('--source', required=True)
#parser.add_argument('--destinations', required=True)
#args = parser.parse_args()
id = 0
source = "United-States"
with open("data1.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["id", "source_country", "destination_country", "competitor_name", "transfer_rate", "amount"])
    destinations = "mexico,brazil"#str(args.destinations)
    destinations = destinations.split(",")
    for destination in destinations:
        url = 'https://www.worldremit.com/en/'+ destination
        r = requests.get(url,verify=False)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
```

Comment: Where is that field? I can't see it.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I added the image to this post. The value to be extracted is marked in green

Comment: @RaghunandanPalakodety, you need to send GET to [this](https://www.worldremit.com/wa/api/v2/calculations/defaults-preview?sendCountry=gb&receiveCountry=mx).

Answer (score 0):

Since the content you are looking for is dynamically generated we will use `json`.

```
import argparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import csv
import requests
#parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#parser.add_argument('--source', required=True)
#parser.add_argument('--destinations', required=True)
#args = parser.parse_args()
id = 0
source = "United-States"
with open("data1.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["id", "source_country", "destination_country", "competitor_name", "transfer_rate", "amount"])
    destinations = "gb,us" #str(args.destinations)
    destinations = destinations.split(",")
    for destination in destinations:
        response = requests.get(f'https://www.worldremit.com/wa/api/v2/calculations/defaults-preview?sendCountry={destination}&receiveCountry=mx') #Change URL here
        json_element = response.json()
        print(text['payoutMethodCalculations'][0]['exchangeRate'], text['payoutMethodCalculations'][0]['fee'], sep='\n')
```

Output: -

```
{'baseCurrency': 'GBP', 'counterCurrency': 'MXN', 'amount': 26.04374, 'roundedAmount': 26.04}
{'amount': 2.99, 'currency': 'GBP'}
{'baseCurrency': 'USD', 'counterCurrency': 'MXN', 'amount': 19.74055, 'roundedAmount': 19.74}
{'amount': 2.99, 'currency': 'USD'}
```